# Change bookmark level in Acrobat Pro DC

Tags: adobe-acrobat, ebook

How do I change the level of a bookmark in Acrobat Pro DC?
I have a PDF file that was generated by FrameMaker and all of the bookmarks are under a top-level bookmark for the name of the book. I don't need a top-level bookmark for the name of the book; I want to move all of the bookmarks below, like "Inside Cover" and "Credits," to the top level. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the old Acrobat XI, but I suppose that the procedure will be the same:

1. *Select all bookmarks.*
   (Click on the icon near an arbitrary of them to select it, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click at the topmost one (“The UNIX-HATERS handbook”)  to *deselect it.*

   Now all bookmarks except the first one are selected.
3. Drag the icon near the first selected bookmark to the left and just under the first (not selected) one *until you will see the tiny guideline.*

   Now all bookmarks are shifted one level up (i.e., to the left).
4. Click the icon near the first (unselected) bookmark to select it.
   (It will become the only selected bookmark).
5. Click on the *trash icon* above to *delete it* (if you don't need it).

Now repeat the procedure for selecting all except the first (“Inside Cover”) bookmark – see steps 1 and 2 above.

Then repeat the step 3, however drag the icon not totally to the left, but a little to the right. The tiny gridline will show you the correct position - the 2<sup>nd</sup> level.